# Windows 10 - How to disable Share tab in File Explorer Ribbon?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, zip, ribbon

On Windows 10, I want to hide the Share tab in the File Explorer Ribbon. Is there any registry key, group policy, or file modification that will let me do this? Please note that I don't want to get rid of the Ribbon altogether, just this particular tab.

If the tab can't be removed, is there any way to at least remove the Zip icon from it? I am trying to weed out all traces of the (terrible) built-in Zip support from Windows. On Windows 7, this could be done by deleting a few registry keys. However, after deleting these on Windows 10, the built-in Zip functionality is still triggered if the Zip button on the Share tab is used. Alternatively, can the Zip button be made to utilize 7-Zip instead?